# Python Chromedriver to interact with iframe

Tags: python, iframe, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Python and Chromedriver to open a company internal page.

When the page is loaded, it pops up "terms and condition". It is an iframe, user needs to click the “Agree” button to close it, before continue with the main page.

I used Katalon Recorder to simulate clicking. It returns this line:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Agree").click()
```

But when I integrated it with headless Chrome driver, error says it cannot find the element.

In the code, I already switch to the iframe before the click “Agree”. The switch to iframe seems ok because there's no error message.

A strange thing is, I used below to scroll down to the page bottom (before switching to iframe), but it doesn't scroll:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
```

Another workaround, after the main page is loaded and the pop-up appeared, I can manually (using pyautogui) move the cursor outside the pop-up and 1 click. The iframe will disappear.

But if I use the manual cursor move, Chromedriver headless is meaningless because I need to keep it always on top of other windows (otherwise the manual mouse move and click are not on the webpage).

How shall I handle this problem? (please excuse me not able to post an example and code, because it’s company internal page)

On the iframe, the “Agree” xpath looks like:

```
/html/body/appcues/cue/div/div/a
```

On the other hand, is there a way to simulate mouse move and click in Chrome driver itself instead of pyautogui?

Comment: It is a good idea to wait a bit after switching to iframe. Try waiting for the element to be clickable.

Comment: driver.wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "myXpath"))).click()

Comment: Can you share the link of the platform you are testing? We need to practise on it.

Comment: @dpapadopoulos, sorry that I am not able to do it, as it's not a public accessible page.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Try the recommended way above, but from my side, I can't help randomly or guessing what is not working without practice on that. Hope you will find it out :)